# Nodejs, an unknown value was passed to the validate function, But I Cant find whats wrong with

Tags: node.js, validation, nestjs

Thank you for stopping by for help.
I have API woring on using NodeJs,
It has 3 arguments It accepts, but It seems like there is an issue on validation.
When I call the API, It gives me this result,

```
[{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "an unknown value was passed to the validate function"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}]
```

Help me anyone can tell what's wrong with this!

I put three arguments, in order of,

- `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5Y3fpHg45U`
- `1`
- `JP`

and there goes my code

```
  /**
   * Gets Subtitle From Youtube
   * @param getYoutubeSubtitleDto
   */
  public async getSubtitle(
    getYoutubeSubtitleDto: GetYoutubeSubtitleDto,
  ): Promise<Subtitle[]> { 
    const { videoId, lang, projectId } = getYoutubeSubtitleDto
    return this.getOrCreateSubtitles(videoId, lang, projectId)
  }
```

```
export class GetYoutubeSubtitleDto extends Video {
  @ApiProperty()
  @IsNumber()
  @Type(() => Number)
  projectId: number

  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Translation Language' })
  @IsString()
  lang: string
}
```

```
export const YOUTUBE_LINK_REGEX = /http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/watch\?v=|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\w\?‌​=]*)?/

export class Video {
  @ApiProperty({ description: 'Youtube Link' })
  @IsString()
  @Matches(YOUTUBE_LINK_REGEX)
  video: string

  public get videoId(): string { 
    return YOUTUBE_LINK_REGEX.exec(this.video)[1]
  }
}
```

Comment: This return when you use the "forbidUnknownValues" validator option in the validate or validateOrReject methods. Can you check if that is the case?

Comment: Can you add your controller code?

Comment: I encountered this issue and ended up finding that DTOs must NOT be imported via `import type` due to `"importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"`

Comment: @pearllv did you find a solution to this?. i've a simillar problem here https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/1663

Answer (score 19):

Set your `forbidUnknownValues` flag to false in `main.ts/bootstrap/useGlobalPipes`

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      forbidUnknownValues: false
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, but i'm curious how you know this?

Comment: @MaxTaylor-Hayden everything could be found in docs (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)

Comment: Known bug introduced in class-validator version 0.14.0 (probably won't be fixed): https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/1873

Answer (score 19):

For anyone looking for a proper solution and an explanation rather than just a solution that bypasses the error...

This error happens when you have registered a global `ValidationPipe`:

```js
/* main.ts */
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe())
```

or a local (on endpoint level):

```js
@Post()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
async save(@Query() dto: SomeDto) { ... }
```

In this case NestJS validate request parameters and if it doesn't match the specified type you will get error saying:

> "an unknown value was passed to the validate function".

In most cases your request includes some additional data that is not expected/defined in the endpoint signature, or you are just missing a proper type information on DTOs or classes that are expected as input types.

For instance if you have a function in controller, defined like this:

```js
@Get('/list')
async getList(@Query() dto: MyDto): Promise<List> {
  return this.listService.getList(dto);
}

// ...

class MyDto {
  @IsString()
  name: string;

  @IsString()
  surname: string;
}
```

and you'll pass in the `{name: 'A', surname: 'B', age: 42}`, you will get an error since `age` is not expected to be passed in.

Sometimes finding those errors can be time consuming and one simple trick to help you out is to implement your custom `exceptionFactory` and pass it to `ValidationPipe` where you can print out the error which includes some additional metadata:

```js
/* main.ts */
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({exceptionFactory: (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    throw new BadRequestException('You shall not pass!');
  }
}))
```

This won't solve your problem but will at least give you an information which type is not correct and you can start from there.

### Recommended solution

If you are sure that you are passing correct payload, but do not want to set `forbidUnknownValues` like other suggested, then most likely one or more of your class/DTO is most likely lacking some type declarations that are needed for successful validation of payload. For me, most of the time I was missing a proper type definitions for nested (non-primitive) properties, or for an arrays of objects.

```js
import {IsString, ValidateNested} from 'class-validator';
import {Type} from 'class-transformer';

//...

// Primitive type
@IsString()
name: string;

// Nested objects
@Type(() => Coach)
coach: Coach;

// Validate array of objects/entities
@ValidateNested({ each: true })
@Type(() => Player)
players: Player[];
```

You can read more about request validation in [Validation chapter](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) in documentation.

Comment: This should be considered the right solution

Comment: This was the same issue I was facing with NestJS after upgrading to class-validator 0.14.0

Comment: The decorator @Type should be imported from 'class-transformer' 

`import { Type } from 'class-transformer';`
more info: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#working-with-nested-objects

Comment: This is great. A small note that was driving me crazy, if you've added other options like forbidNonWhitelisted you also need to remember to add the appropriate validation decorators to the fields in the nested class.

Comment: That is a great note @miguelsavignano. I'll update the answer to make it more clear

Comment: @metodribic you mention a DTO missing properties, but in my case I'm doing a GET (so no body) and I'm trying to get the `@Param` to transform a string to an MongoDB ObjectId.  The Pipe works and transforms the value, and you can test the result using `typeof projectId`, but if I have a signature of `@Param('projectId', ParseObjectIdPipe) projectId: ObjectId` I'll get the validation error, which goes away if I make it a string like `@Param('projectId', ParseObjectIdPipe) projectId: string` even though `projectId` isn't a string

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone encounter this error after updating class-validator. Please see the breaking changes in the [change log](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md).
In addition to the previous solutions. In my case the error was thrown because I wasn't validating the DTO class.

Wrong

```
class SampleDTO {
  prop?: string;
}
```

Correct

```
class SampleDTO {
  @IsString()
  prop?: string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked for me. My input field enums needed validation 
`@IsEnum(enum)`

Answer (score -2):

You must use *whitelist* in combination with *forbidNonWhitelisted*,

References:

> we can whitelist the acceptable properties, and any property not included in the whitelist is automatically stripped from the resulting object

> Alternatively, you can stop the request from processing when non-whitelisted properties are present, and return an error response to the user. To enable this, set the forbidNonWhitelisted option property to true, in combination with setting whitelist to true

This works for me:

```js
<ValidationOptions> {
  forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
  whitelist: true,
}
```

NestJS has a section about this [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#stripping-properties).